# guava converter for Function<T, Boolean> to Predicate<T>

Tags: java, guava, predicate

In guava, is there a convenience for converting a `Function<T, Boolean>` to a `Predicate<T>`?

In `Functions`, I can see `Function<T, Boolean> forPredicate(Predicate<T> predicate)` but I don't see anything for going in the other direction.

The code I have to write myself currently is:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> functionToPredicate(final Function<T, Boolean> func) {
    return new Predicate<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(T input) {
            return func.apply(input);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but your method looks good!

Comment: Assuming Java 8: `Predicate<T> p = func::apply;`

Comment: How often would you actually need such a convenience?  Why wouldn't you write your `Function` as a `Predicate` in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with converting a `Function<A, Boolean>` to a `Predicate<A>` is that whereas the latter can return `true` or `false`, the former can also return `null` (and, of course, actually returns `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`).

With this in mind, your suggested implementation could actually throw a `NullPointerException`, if the function happens to return `null` for some input, which isn't something you can guard against simply using the type system.

Modifying your suggestion:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> functionToPredicate(final Function<? super T, Boolean> function, boolean valueForNull) {
  return new Predicate<T>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(T input) {
      Boolean value = func.apply(input);
      return (value != null) ? value.booleanValue() : valueForNull;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you could use [Predicates.compose](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#compose%28com.google.common.base.Predicate,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

```
Predicate<T> predicate = Predicates.compose(
        Predicates.equalTo(Boolean.TRUE), function);
```

for the case when you want to treat `null` as `false`, or

```
Predicate<T> predicate = Predicates.not(Predicates.compose(
        Predicates.equalTo(Boolean.FALSE), function));
```

for the case when you want to treat `null` as `true`.